# Is it possible to find a nash equilibrium that is not an equilibrium in weakly dominant strategy?

Tags: game-theory, nash-equilibrium, dominant-strategy

I know that it is possible to have a Nash equilibrium which is not an equilibrium in dominant strategy, but is it also applicable for equilibrium in weakly dominant strategy (i.e. a Nash equilibrium which is NOT an equilibrium in weakly dominant strategy)? If yes, what would be an example?

Answer (score 2):

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
&L&R\\\hline
T&1,1&0,0\\\hline
B&0,0&0,0\\\hline
\end{array}

In the game above, there are two pure strategy Nash equilibria:

- $(T,L)$ is an equilibrium in weakly domi**nant** strategies;
- $(B,R)$ is an equilibrium in weakly domi**nated** strategies.

Noting that "dominant" and "dominated" are two different words, I believe the above example answers both the question in your post as well as your question in the comment below.

Comment: This is not the question I asked. I asked about Nash equilibrium which is NOT an equilibrium in weakly dominated strategies.

Comment: @Aqqqq Actually, this is the answer to the question you asked! You edited the question later. This is clear from the [edit history](https://economics.stackexchange.com/posts/32884/revisions).

Comment: @Giskard I edited the question to make it clearer for understanding. No meaning was changed. The only thing I added was the content in the bracket.

Comment: @Aqqqq Sorry (though I am completely right and adding contradictory information in brackets does not change this).

Comment: @Aqqqq: Your question asks for NE that's not in weakly domi**nant** strategies. $(B,R)$ is NOT a Nash equilibrium in weakly domi**nant** strategies, it's in weakly domi**nated** strategies.

Comment: @Giskard Does not sound contradictory for me. I only realized after seeing this answer that this could be misunderstanding. Also did you even read the question title?

Comment: @Aqqqq I believe you. Herr K's answer does answer both your questions though.